# Inheritance of TYPO3 models

Tags: typo3, mixins

I have a tricky question about the inheritance of TYPO3 models:

I want to extend the extension powermail with two seperate/independed (!) extensions. The first extend powermail TCA-forms and needs the new fields in the fluid template. The second extends also the TCA-forms, but not need an output in the frontend.

Now I use the mixed-ins hack from Franz Koch http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-project-typo3v4mvc/2010-September/006497.html which using the delete field as record type. But this solution works only for one extension. According to the loading of the TS persistence settings either the first or the second model of the extension will be loaded.

If I use an own field for the record type – eg. for the field record of powermail – I can use only **one** record type for the one extension, but can't access to the other.

Is there a way to "merge" ALL models related to the base model?

Next current TS config:

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {

            # Using mixed-ins hack from Franz Koch to make map table extendable.
            # @see http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-project-typo3v4mvc/2010-September/006497.html
            Tx_Powermail_Domain_Model_Fields {
                mapping.recordType = 0
                subclasses.0 = Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Powermail\Fields
            }

            Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Powermail\Fields {
                mapping {
                    tableName = tx_powermail_domain_model_fields
                    recordType = 0
                    columns {
                        tx_myfirstextension_field_one.mapOnProperty = FieldOne
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ext_tables.php:

```
// Using mixed-ins hack from Franz Koch to make map table extendable.
// @see http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-project-typo3v4mvc/2010-September/006497.html
$TCA['tx_powermail_domain_model_forms']['ctrl']['type'] = 'deleted';
$TCA['tx_powermail_domain_model_pages']['ctrl']['type'] = 'deleted';
$TCA['tx_powermail_domain_model_fields']['ctrl']['type'] = 'deleted';
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a solution, but with another problem. I could fetch raw data `setReturnRawQueryResult(TRUE)`. But with this there will be an error cause there is a call of `getFirst` on an array. (http://forge.typo3.org/issues/46035)

Comment: What kind of fields do you want to add, how should they be displayed in the frontend?

Comment: The first extension added some style fields to powermail. These are needed as Fluid variables. If the second extension don't override the first subclasses it works. Cause I need for the second extension "only" internal requests I resolved it with an own query `$query = $fieldsRepository->createQuery(); $query->setReturnRawQueryResult(TRUE);` and execute the query without `getFirst`: `$query->matching($query->equals('uid', $uid))->execute();`. So I get an array instead of the model. A better solution will be welcom, but I think it's on the wishlist to get full featured mixins for PHP/TYPO3 :)